# Can I use require('img.jpg') to load img file on local server within background-image style property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Can I use require('img.jpg') to load img file on local server within background-image style property?

To load img files in a react app on a local server I use 
`<img src=     {require('./greenLine.jpg')}` /> 
after installing `url-loader` and `file-loader`.

This works great, but I want to use the img file in a style object, like - `const divBkground = { backgroundImage: require('url(./greenLine.jpg)')`}

This doesn't work. Can someone advise?

THANKS..

Answer (score 1):

You need not use `require` when you try to define a style for background image . Just the simple `backgroundImage: 'url(./greenLine.jpg)'` works fine

```
const divBkground = { 
    backgroundImage: 'url(./greenLine.jpg)'
}
```

Comment: Thanks - That's not working for local image files. If I use an image that's on line it works, but for an app served on localhost there's an issue related to to cross server issue?. That's why the url loader and require are needed. It works for img tag  but not for backgroung-image. AM I missing something?

Comment: it should be like so: `body { background-image: url('../path/to/image'); }`